# How to make 2 computers on different subnets communicate via sockets?

Tags: c#, objective-c, .net, sockets, client-server

I have written a Server application on my Mac in Objective C with the following socket settings-

```
addr4.sin_len = sizeof(addr4);
addr4.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr4.sin_port = htons(6832); 
addr4.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
if (kCFSocketSuccess != CFSocketSetAddress(_ipv4socket, (__bridge CFDataRef) [NSData dataWithBytes:&addr4 length:sizeof(addr4)])) {
    [self stop];
    return NO;
}
```

And its IP = `ABC.DEF.64.188` and subnet mask = `255.255.255.0`

My client is in C# with the following socket settings -

```
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve("ABC.DEF.64.188");
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

// Create a TCP/IP socket.
 client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

The IP address of the Windows machine = `ABC.DEF.205.118`(Found using What is my IP?). I guess the windows machine is behind a NAT with the following settings -

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : stonybrook.edu
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::cd7d:846d:564a:3fa5%12
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.24.17.97
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.24.16.1
```

I am getting the following error at the client and the server never sees a new incoming connection-

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 130.245.64.188:6832    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

Firewall is disabled on both machines. It works just fine when both the machines are on the same subnet.

How to make this connection work?

Comment: It could possibly be a port issue; `ABC.DEF.64.188` is using port `6832` and in your setting, but what port is the connecting machine using?

Comment: @I'L'I 6832 is the port number I've chosen on both computers.

Comment: Interesting — what happens if you try and ping the `188` host on port `6832` from the other?

Comment: @I'L'I Sorry. I came to college, unable to make the connection work. I'll try ur suggestion when I get back home